# Service worker image status code

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I try to detect error 404 of images with a service worker.
Is there a way to get the status code of an image fetch?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

    console.log('Handling fetch event for %s', event.request.url);

    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {

            if (response.status == 200) {
                return response;                    
            }
            else {
                /* return some default image */
            }

        })        
    );

});
```

This code works well with html files, but when it fetches an image, the status code is always 0. Is there a way to get status code of the images? I removed the cache and everything else to make my example simple.

This is the sample page I tried to load:

```
<body>
    <!-- This image is working -->
    <img src="http://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
    <!-- This image returns 404 -->
    <img src="http://www.google.ca/images/srpr/00000.png">
</body>
```

So the html page itself status is 200 but both of the images return status of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting back an [opaque filtered response](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque), which is expected when your request doesn't use CORS. The `status` of `0` is intentionally vague in this case—if a real status code were used, then information that otherwise wouldn't be available without CORS would leak.

There's some background in this `fetch` spec [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/14).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#responses), a status of `0` represents an error. You may want to check the status message. My guess is that this is a CORS-related error, since you're fetching from a third-party site. From Matt Gaunt's [Introduction to Service Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/):

> By default, fetching a resource from a third party URL will fail if it
>   doesn't support CORS. You can add a non-CORS option to the Request to
>   overcome this, although this will cause an 'opaque' response, which
>   means you won't be able to tell if the response was successful or not.

Try setting `mode: 'no-cors'` as he suggests there.